# Run through multiple dataframes in a for loop, and use assign to give output in R

Tags: r

I have recreated a simplified version of my problem using `mtcars`.  I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 <- mtcars %>% filter(mpg > 20)
df2 <- mtcars %>% filter(mpg < 20)
```

eg.

```
head(df1)
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2

dim(df1)
[1] 14 11
```

I want to create two new objects, `nrows_df1` and `nrows_df2`, which both say the number of rows of the respective data frames, eg:

```
nrow_df1
[1] 14
```

I tried doing the following:

```
for (df in c(df1, df2)) {
    nam <- paste("nrows_", deparse(substitute(df)))
    assign(nam, nrow(df))
}
```

But it doesn't work.  What is the correct code to create these variables, using the for loop?

Comment: "The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should never use the assign function." - Greg Snow, R-help (July 2009)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the correct way would be not to create such multiple dataframes having multiple corresponding variables in the global environment. Keep the dataframes in a list and you can do everything using this list itself using `sapply`/`lapply` :

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2)
n_rows <- sapply(df_list, nrow)
n_rows
#[1] 14 18
```

For the sake of completing the answer to get two separate variables in global environment, you can create a named list and use `list2env`.

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(n_rows), 
         paste0('nrow_df', seq_along(df_list))), .GlobalEnv)
nrow_df1
#[1] 14
nrow_df2
#[1] 18
```